# Choose a Layout file based on a SQL Query in _Viewstart file

Tags: sql, asp.net-core

I am new to programming so bear with me if I explain this wrong.

I have an ASP.NET Core web application using Entity Framework that will allow users to access a SQL database and perform CRUD operations.  One of the tables is "Users" and one of the fields in that table is "Permissions".  Another field is the Windows username of the user.  Ultimately I would like to have a different Layout file used for different permission levels.  I know there are better ways to do this (authentication/authorization) but for now I am just trying to have different layouts for different users.

I have tried the following code in the _Viewstart file but I get the error "Database does not exist in the current context".  Is there a way to extract a value from a SQL table in the viewstart file?

Alternately, is there a better way to do this that is not overly complicated?

I am also using Windows Identity to get the current user and compare that to the table in the database.

```
var db = Database.Open("My Connection String");
var selectQueryString = "Select Permissions FROM Users WHERE UserName = User.Identity.Name";

int currentuser = db.Query(selectQueryString);

if (currentuser == 1) Layout = "_Layout";
else Layout = "_Layout2";
```

Answer (score 1):

> to have different layouts for different users"

### Update

In the **razor page** project, to dynamically change the layout based on user information, you can pass different layout values based on user information by creating a **`BindProperty`** type field and dynamically bind the Layout in the page.

Index.cshtml.cs:

```
    [BindProperty]
    public string Layout { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    { 
        var db = Database.Open("My Connection String");
        var selectQueryString = "Select Permissions FROM Users WHERE UserName = User.Identity.Name";

        int currentuser = db.Query(selectQueryString);
        if (currentuser == 1) Layout = "_Layout";
        else Layout = "_Layout2";

    }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@page
@model WebApplication_razorpage_new.Pages.IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/" + Model.Layout + ".cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do I then have a file "_ViewStart.cshtml" and also a "_ViewStart.cshtml.cs" like a razor page?  To clarify, this is a razor pages project, not MVC.

Comment: @Mike , I have updated my reply to meet your requirement in razor page project.